# Can you use pip from within a PyInstaller executable?

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

If PyInstaller comes with a python interpreter. And Python comes with pip (> 3.4). Can you access pip from within the PyInstaller executable? I am having issues doing so. I have tried.

1. Using pip directly within executable code.

```
import pip

pip.main(['install', 'package'])
```

but get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.commands.install'`

2. Using subprocess

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
```

but get `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/Users/username/workspace/app/server/dist/server/server', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'tldextract']' returned non-zero exit status 1.` I'm pretty sure this fails because the location isn't actually the python interpreter but the bootloader.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? Once you have shipped a PyInstaller executable can you pip install new packages into that enviroment?

Comment: "*If PyInstaller comes with a python interpreter.*" PyInstaller comes with a python interpreter but not with a full Python library. PyInstaller cuts the library to bare minimum. You have to direct PyInstaller to include `pip`, `setuptools` and `pkg_resources` into the generated installer.

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ#misc: "*You can not run an external Python script, as PyInstaller does not provide a python executable. You have some options to work around this…*"

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports

Comment: @phd Thank you for reading this. So it sounds like you think it is possible? I had originally tried adding `pip`.  And I can import it but it doesn't seem to function. But maybe if I also include `setuptools` and `pkg_resources` in the `hidden_imports`?

Comment: Ok you inspired me. I kinda got it working just throwing the kitchen sink at it. Using `from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all` and including `collect_all('pip')` and `collect_all('pkg_resources')` and `collect_all('setuptools')` I can probably work back and see which things I can ignore. Some packages aren't working as they are using `sys.executable -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/......` but maybe there is a way around that.... Any ideas with that?

Comment: Hmm unfortunately thats a good number of packages...

Comment: @GlenThompson Have you ever found a satisfying solution for this?

Comment: Tried many different things but there are many *commands* packages within distutils that don't get included by pyinstaller, even if you declare them as hidden. Very interested in a solution as well.